# What did Luther and Calvin believe about "Lucifer" in Isaiah 14?

Tags: church-history, reformed-theology, satan, martin-luther, calvin

To many Christians Lucifer of Isaiah 14 (not to be confused with Satan) is considered a visually beautiful, Rock n' Rolling cherub who fell from heaven to deceive mankind. And according to a few websites (e.g. [Vigilant Citizen](https://vigilantcitizen.com/moviesandtv/lucy-movie-luciferian-philosophy/)) he is the heroic demigod who gave man knowledge of good and evil Prometheus style, and is revered and worshiped by the media and politicians.

What did Martin Luther and John Calvin think of this character?

Comment: Beautiful?  Rock n' Rolling?  Omnipotent?  Heroic?  Feared and hated only by "many" Christians?  What an odd lead-in to your question --- but it does leave clear what you think of Lucifer's character.  Personally, I know him to be the [father of lies](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/5.24?lang=eng&clang=eng#p23).

Comment: For the purpose of this question are you equating Lucifer with Satan?

Comment: @JBH I'm actually talking about a different character than Satan. Satan is in the Bible. When I think of Satan I think of 1 Kings 22:22. When I think of Lucifer, I think of [this](http://www.jesus-is-savior.com/) on the Christian side (check it out it's pretty interesting really) and [this](https://vigilantcitizen.com/) for the media.

Comment: @bradimus No I don't believe them to be the same character. Check out my reply to JBH and hopefully that will clear it up.

Comment: @JBH Isn't that the usual description of Lucifer? I heard he was the most beautiful of all God's creation, and that he was a cherub and leader of the music in heaven until he tried to overtake God's throne. So God cast him down to earth where he deceived Adam and Eve, and now he uses popular music and the governments to spread his NWO agenda.

Comment: Both the websites linked to are large with numerous links and Lucifer seems not prominently mentioned, at least by name. Please could you say where  exactly in the sites we should  look, and if not mentioned by name how you suspect he is being referenced.?

Comment: Questions about [Mick Jagger](https://www.amazon.com/Mick-Jagger-Everybodys-Lucifer-Scaduto-ebook/dp/B007M2JU3M) do not belong on Christianity.SE.

Comment: @davidlol [Here is an article](https://vigilantcitizen.com/moviesandtv/lucy-movie-luciferian-philosophy/) from Vigilant Citizen about Luciferianism. The other website exposed the same things as Vigilant, but [here is an article about Lucifer](http://www.jesusisprecious.org/bible/easy_to_read_lie.htm)

Comment: This question should really ask how they read Isaiah 14 going by the self answer you've given.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast A lot of what's on that Vigilant Citizen site is how young or extremely popular "stars" are killed. Kinda makes me wonder what Mick Jagger meant by "And I laid traps for troubadours
Who get killed before they reached Bombay"

Comment: @anonymouswho  Apologies for a memory lapse, but I think Keith Richard covered that in his autobiography, which I read a few years ago and then passed on to a friend.  No ref available.

Comment: It seems to me that the materials for the answer to this question are found in [a larger discussion of this issue on Hermeneutics.SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/8068/2215). If, in fact, that was an inspiration (or even a source) for this material, some acknowledgement would probably be appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Although Calvin and Luther most certainly believed in an entity called Satan, they deny that Isaiah 14:12 has any connection with the devil or that *Lucifer* is his name. In [Calvin's commentary of Isaiah 14](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/cal/isaiah-14.html), he says:

> How art thou fallen from heaven! Isaiah proceeds with the discourse which he had formerly begun as personating the dead, and concludes that the tyrant differs in no respect from other men, though his object was to lead men to believe that he was some god. He employs an elegant **metaphor, by comparing him to Lucifer**, and calls him the Son of the Dawn; (220) and that on account of his splendor and brightness with which he shone above others. **The exposition of this passage, which some have given, as if it referred to Satan, has arisen from ignorance**; for the context plainly shows that these statements must be understood in reference to the king of the Babylonians. **But when passages of Scripture are taken up at random, and no attention is paid to the context, we need not wonder that mistakes of this kind frequently arise**. Yet it was an instance of **very gross ignorance, to imagine that Lucifer was the king of devils**, and that the Prophet gave him this name. **But as these inventions have no probability whatever, let us pass by them as useless fables**.

In [Franz Delitzsch commentary of Isaiah](https://archive.org/stream/biblicalcommenta1deliuoft#page/310/mode/1up), he quotes Martin Luther, saying:

> Lucifer, the name of the devil, is derived from this passage, the reference of which to **Satan is designated by Luther as *insignis error totius papatus***; but it is found already in Jerome and other Fathers.

According to Delitzsch, Luther believed the designation of this passage to Satan to be *insignis error totius papatus* or *a noteworthy error of the papacy*. [1](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/8068/15608)

### Conclusion

Neither Martin Luther nor John Calvin believed there was such a character named Lucifer. They respectively blamed this error on the Catholic church and referred to this notion as nothing more than fairy tales and fables.

---

1. Source and translation from Davïd's excellent and much more thorough answer to [Why is Isaiah 14:12-15 interpreted by some to refer to Satan?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/8068/15608) at BH.SE

Comment: I suspect that you are as old as I am, in that you appear to enjoy talking to yourself.  It's OK, at least the wisest one in the room is your partner in conversation. :)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Haha, no I just wanted to answer the question because everyone thought I was praising Lucifer, when I don't even believe he exists.

Comment: Have you seen the movie "The Usual Suspects" lately? :-)

Comment: *But when passages of Scripture are taken up at random, and no attention is paid to the context, we need not wonder that mistakes of this kind frequently arise* - This describes about half of the questions that come in to this SE.  :p

Comment: You don't seem to have answered what they thought of "the beautiful, musically inclined, Rock n' Rolling, omnipotent fallen angel that is feared and hated by many Christians, and the heroic demigod who gave man knowledge of good and evil" so it would be very fair to flag this as Not An Answer.

Comment: @curiousdannii I edited the question since everyone thought I wasn't hailing Satan or something. Is that better?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast No I've never seen that movie. It looks funny though. Have you ever seen the Disney cartoon [Gravity Falls](https://vigilantcitizen.com/moviesandtv/gravity-falls-a-new-disney-tv-show-loaded-with-illuminati-symbolism/)?

Comment: @anonymouswho Not yet, but I suppose I will.